# Reason behind the choice of the 0.05 p-value threshold value

Tags: p-value

I just would like to understand the basis and rational why 0.05 is widely used as the accepted value to decide **rare** or **unlikely**.

Is p-value threshold related with the confidence interval or +/- $2\sigma$ as the basis for 5%?

Comment: Both the $0.05$ and $2$ standard deviations came from [RA Fisher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Fisher) who as a practical statistician doing field experiments (literally, at [Rothamsted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rothamsted_Research)) had found this provided empirically useful criteria as to whether to investigate a question further.  They are related in that $\Phi(1.96)\approx 0.975$ though not all statistical tests use the normal distribution.  He also stated that other scientists might prefer to use other cutt-offs for their own reasons

Comment: There's a saying: if you ask somebody in industry why they use $0.05$ they'll tell you "it's because that's what they were taught in school". If you ask somebody in academia why they teach $0.05$, it's because "that's what they use in industry".

Answer (score 1):

I think that is the opposite.  People first started to use 5% as the threshold for "rare" events.  Then, since the 97.5-th percentile of the standard normal distribution is around 1.97, people also started to use the 2$\sigma$ rule for convenience.
In my understanding, choosing 5% in the first place is only a historical convention.
I would be interested in hearing other opinions, though.